# Non-differentiability of Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing, solution-verification

I know that there already exist some questions on this issue but I want to know if my proof is right. So here again is *Thomae's*-function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \text{ ; when } x \text{ is irrational} \\\frac 1 q \text{ ; for } x=\frac p q \text{ irreducible fraction}.\end{cases}$$

I want to show that it is nowhere differentiable. I will only show it for irrational points as it is obvious for rational points (due to discontinuity).

**My apporach**:

Let be $\pi$ an arbitrary irrational number and $\left(x_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence with $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}x_k=\pi$ and $x_k\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ for all $k$. If we plug the sequence into the differential quotient it becomes:
$$
\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(\pi)}{x_k-\pi}= \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{0-0}{x-\pi}=0.
$$
Now we will use the property that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a unique $p_k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that: $(p_k-1)<\pi k<p_k$ to construct a sequence $\left(a_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rationals as follows:
$$a_0=0,\\
a_1=\frac{p_1}{1}, \text{where } \pi<\frac{p_1}{1}<\pi+\frac{1}{1},\\
\cdots\\
a_n=\frac{p_n}{n}, \text{where } \pi<\frac{p_n}{n}<\pi+\frac{1}{n}.
$$
This sequence converges to $\pi$ due to the squeeze theorem. Now we plug in this sequence into the differential quotient and get:
$$
\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(a_k)-f(\pi)}{a_k-\pi}\geq \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{k}-0}{\frac{p_k}{k}-\pi}=\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{p_k-k\pi}.
$$
The inequality sign "$\geq$" is valid because if the member $a_k=\frac{p_k}{k}$ is not irreducible then it follows $f(\frac{p_k}{k})\geq \frac{1}{k}$. Further  we notice that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{p_n-n\pi}=0$ can only be true *iff* the denominator $(p_n-n\pi)$ tends to $\infty$. However, this is not possible because by definition of our sequence for all $k$ it holds that $p_k-k\pi<1$. So we would have two different limits at the irrational point $\pi$, namely $0$ and some unknown finite value. Hence $f$ is not differentiable at any point.

Is my proof right? Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Why downvoting? Is the question unclear?

Comment: One stylistic point: It's questionable to say "Let $\pi$ be an arbitrary irrational number". While that is allowed, it's better to use something like $\xi$ which isn't the name of such a famous _specific_ irrational number. One small error in your proof: For your rational approximations, the limit of the difference quotient need not exist, and the limit of $\frac{1}{p_k - k\pi}$ certainly does not exist. The fix is to use $\liminf$ instead of $\lim$ there. By your choice of $p_k$ you have $$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{p_k - k\pi} \geqslant 1\,.$$

Comment: It is good that you didn't overlook the possibility that $\frac{p_k}{k}$ may be reducible.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, thanks for the hint with the $\lim \inf$. Haven't thought about this point.